# EF Core Many to Many Join Table with Extra Properties Not Working

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, .net-5, asp.net5

I want to have this join table which has 2 foreign keys but also adds some other properties:

```cs
[Serializable]
public class GroceryItemGroceryStore
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0), Required]
    public int GroceryItemId { get; set; }
    [Key, Column(Order = 1), Required]
    public int GroceryStoreId { get; set; }

    public virtual GroceryItem GroceryItem { get; set; }
    public virtual GroceryStore GroceryStore { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int NotInEstablishmentCount { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int InEstablishmentCount { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public double Price { get; set; }
}
```

Which joins these entities:

```cs
public class GroceryItem : VeganItem<GroceryItemTag, GroceryStore>
{
    public GroceryItem(string name, string brand, string description, string image)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Brand = brand;
        this.Description = description;
        this.Image = image;
    }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Brand { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<GroceryItemGroceryStore> GroceryItemGroceryStores { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public abstract class VeganItem<VeganItemTagType, EstablishmentType>
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int IsNotVeganCount { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int IsVeganCount { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int RatingsCount { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int Rating { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public List<VeganItemTagType> Tags { get; set; }
    //[Required]
    public List<EstablishmentType> Establishments { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int CurrentRevisionId { get; set; }
}
```

and these entities:

```cs
[Serializable]
public class GroceryStore : Establishment<GroceryItem>
{
    public GroceryStore(string name, string placeId, string street, string suburb, string city, string streetNumber)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.PlaceId = placeId;
        this.Street = street;
        this.StreetNumber = streetNumber;
        this.City = city;
        this.Suburb = suburb;
    }
}

[Serializable]
public abstract class Establishment<VeganItemType>
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    [Required]
    public string Name {get; set;}
    [Required]
    public string PlaceId {get; set;}
    [Required]
    public string Street {get; set;}
    public string Suburb {get; set;}
    public string City {get; set;}
    
    public List<VeganItemType> VeganItems {get; set;}
    public string StreetNumber {get; set;}
}
```

So I try to specify my join table as the table to use when defining my many-to-many relationship in my database context:

```cs
builder.Entity<GroceryItem>()
    .HasMany(p => p.Establishments)
    .WithMany(p => p.VeganItems)
    .UsingEntity(j => j.ToTable("GroceryItemGroceryStores"));
```

Something is not quite right because I get this error when I run `dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate`:

> Cannot use table 'GroceryItemGroceryStores' for entity type
> 'GroceryItemGroceryStore' since it is being used for entity type
> 'GroceryItemGroceryStore (Dictionary<string, object>)' and potentially
> other entity types, but there is no linking relationship. Add a
> foreign key to 'GroceryItemGroceryStore' on the primary key properties
> and pointing to the primary key on another entity typed mapped to
> 'GroceryItemGroceryStores'.

Where am I going wrong?

**EDIT - Problem with inserting data**
The tables have all been created successfully. But, `GroceryItemGroceryStores` table and `GroceryStores` table do not get any insertions after inserting a `GroceryItem` which has an establishment on it.

Following is the payload being sent to add a `GroceryItem` which should also add a `GroceryStore` and `GroceryItemGroceryStore`:

```
{
    "name": "yummy fofod",
    "brand": "goodfoobdgffe",
    "description": "dfsad",
    "establishments": [{
        "name": "Macdonalds",
        "street": "Beach Rd",
        "placeId": "fsadfsdfsdfsdfsadfsadfsdf"
    }],
    "tags": [
        {
            "name": "sdf",
            "id": "9",
            "iconCodePoint": 23145
        }
    ]
}
```

And this is the controller that handles the above payload request:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult<GroceryItem>> PostGroceryItem(GroceryItem groceryItem)
{
    _context.GroceryItems.Add(groceryItem);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

    return CreatedAtAction("GetGroceryItem", new { id = groceryItem.Id }, groceryItem);
}
```

Comment: You are trying to define many-to-many relationship between which models/entities?

Comment: `GroceryItem` and `GroceryStore`. In `GroceryItemGroceryStore` I have updated the foreign key names which I think were not what EF Core expected. `GroceryStoreId` becomes `EstablishmentsId`. `GroceryItemId` becomes `VeganItemsId`. If these foreign key names are more correct I can update it in the topmost entity of the question.

Comment: @atiyar And obviously subsequently `GroceryStore` of the same entity (`GroceryItemGroceryStore`) becomes `Establishment` and `GroceryItem` becomes `VeganItem`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The presence of the following two properties -

```cs
public virtual GroceryItem GroceryItem { get; set; }
public virtual GroceryStore GroceryStore { get; set; }
```

in the `GroceryItemGroceryStore` model has already put `GroceryItem` and `GroceryStore` in a many-to-many relationship through the joining entity `GroceryItemGroceryStore`.

Then your relation configuring code is trying to create a new many-to-many relation between them, but trying to use the same joining entity. That's where the problem is, and that's exactly what the error message is saying.

Remove the configuration code, and it should work automatically.

If you want to configure the relationship manually, then change it to -

```cs
builder.Entity<GroceryItemGroceryStore>()
    .HasOne(p => p.GroceryItem)
    .WithMany(p => p.GroceryItemGroceryStores)
    .HasForeignKey(p=> p.GroceryItemId);
    
builder.Entity<GroceryItemGroceryStore>()
    .HasOne(p => p.GroceryStore)
    .WithMany()
    .HasForeignKey(p=> p.GroceryStoreId);
```

Or, even better would be adding the following property -

```cs
public virtual ICollection<GroceryItemGroceryStore> GroceryItemGroceryStores { get; set; }
```

to the `GroceryStore` model, and changing the config to -

```cs
builder.Entity<GroceryItemGroceryStore>()
    .HasOne(p => p.GroceryItem)
    .WithMany(p => p.GroceryItemGroceryStores)
    .HasForeignKey(p=> p.GroceryItemId);
    
builder.Entity<GroceryItemGroceryStore>()
    .HasOne(p => p.GroceryStore)
    .WithMany(p=> p.GroceryItemGroceryStores)
    .HasForeignKey(p=> p.GroceryStoreId);
```

**EDIT:**
You should remove the `Establishments` property from the `VeganItem` model and the `VeganItems` property from the `Establishment` model. Otherwise, they will create a separate many-to-many relationship through a separate joining table.

**EDIT - For inserting data**
Follow the steps below -

1. Create a new `GroceryStore` (e.g. `newStore`) from your payload
2. Insert it to the database
3. Create a new `GroceryItem` (e.g. `newItem`) from the payload
4. Do the following -

```cs
newItem.GroceryItemGroceryStores = new List<GroceryItemGroceryStore>
{
    new GroceryItemGroceryStore { GroceryStoreId = newStore.Id }
};

_context.GroceryItems.Add(newItem);
await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Comment: Cheers I have added that virtual collection. In your bottom code block should `WithMany(p => p.GroceryItemGroceryStores)` be something else? As It gives the error `'GroceryItemGroceryStore' does not contain a definition for 'GroceryItemGroceryStores'`

Comment: @BeniaminoBaggins Sorry, my mistake. Check the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks. It seems to be creating 2 join tables: `GroceryItemGroceryStore` and `GroceryItemGroceryStores`, and inserting only the foreign keys into `GroceryItemGroceryStore` and not inserting anything into `GroceryItemGroceryStores`

Comment: Worth noting I have this `public DbSet<GroceryItemGroceryStore> GroceryItemGroceryStores { get; set; }`

Comment: @BeniaminoBaggins Check the Edit please.

Comment: I have updated every part of my question with my current code because I did change my property names to be more universally consistent throughout my app so any establishment has `VeganItems` and any veganItem has `Establishments`. I believe I have implemented your answer just changing the field names. But Now I have the `GroceryItemGroceryStores` table which is great, but nothing gets inserted into it.

Comment: @BeniaminoBaggins I think you should have kept it as it was, and post a new question with the modification. The answer I posted doesn't make any sense anymore against your current code.

Comment: It is only two properties that changed. GroceryStore.GroceryItem > GroceryStore.VeganItem and GroceryItem.GroceryStore > GroceryItem.Establishment

Comment: I can edit your answer field names if you like

Comment: @BeniaminoBaggins Ok. I see now - the changes you made in naming will not make any changes in what I suggested in the answer, or in the tables generated, and it should still work. So, what's not working?

Comment: Let me know if you want me to edit the property names in your answer to follow my new naming conventions, and I can also delete most of the conversation at the end to be concise. I think I have applied your answer to my code - which is now posted in the original question - I only did that so that you could see what I did, since it still has one issue - the tables are all good but GroceryItemGroceryStores table does not get any insertions after inserting a groceryItem which has an establishment on it.

Comment: GroceryStores table has no insertions. However GroceryItems table does

Comment: @BeniaminoBaggins It should work. Now it depends on how you are doing it. I'd suggest you post another question with codes showing how you are trying to insert. As for what I said about keeping post as it was - according to your current edit, that error message in your post, or  what I mentioned about the configuration code, or how to configure etc isn't making any sense  :) Have you noticed that ?

Comment: Yep I understand that is an issue. I have changed the question back to your first edit so it all makes sense again, and added my request payload and associated controller to the bottom of the question which can be deleted after you have seen.

Comment: @BeniaminoBaggins Create a new `GroceryStore` (e.g. newStore) from your payload. Insert it. Once that inserted, create a new `GroceryItem` (e.g. newItem) from the payload. Then `newItem.GroceryItemGroceryStores = new List<GroceryItemGroceryStore>{new GroceryItemGroceryStore{GroceryStoreId=newStore.Id}}; _context.GroceryItems.Add(newItem); await _context.SaveChangesAsync();`

Comment: Almost embarrassingly It still doesn't work XD "The value of 'GroceryItemGroceryStore.EstablishmentId is unknown when attempting to save changes. This is because the property is also part of a foreign key for which the principal entity in the relationship is not known". I am definitely on a better road after your last comment though as I wasn't doing any of that and definitely need to.

Comment: @BeniaminoBaggins Most probably, `GroceryStore` didn't get inserted. You have to _insert_ it first to the database, with a `SaveChanges()` call.

Comment: That works. Thanks so much for all the help! Seriously. It was a lot of effort. Delete all these messages if you like to make the question a bit better for others viewing. Cheers!